# Build failed using Gradle for spring source files

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle

I followed https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework link.
I successfully downloaded spring source with command
**git clone git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework.git**
But when i run 
**./gradlew build** excpetion is thrown  with message Execution failed for task':spring-core:compile Java. I am so confused .How to solve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework#building-from-source:

> > prerequisites: Git and the **latest Early Access build of OpenJDK 1.8**.